# Conveying computationally (talking about algorithms; e.g. computationally ineficient/expensive) avec computationnellement

Tags: expressions, traduction, anglais, usage, informatique

> Cramer's method [1] is computationally inefficient/expensive.

> La méthode de Cramer [1] est insuffisante sur le plan des calculs.
>
> La méthode de Cramer est insuffisante computationnellement.
>
> La méthode de Cramer est coûteuse sur le plan des calculs.
>
> La méthode de Cramer est coûteuse computationnellement.

Peut-on rendre les tournures comme "computationally expensive/inefficient" employant l'adverbe *computationnellement* ? Est-ce mieux d'utiliser "sur le plan des calculs" ? Existe-t-il une autre tournure ?

[1] Pour la résolution des systèmes des équations linéaires algébriques.

Comment: On pourrait dire *calculatoirement*, pas très joli

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En tout état de cause les deux premières affirmations sont fausses.

La méthode de Cramer ne peut pas être dite *insuffisante*. Ce serait dire qu'il manque quelque chose, qu'elle ne suffit pas à la résolution, qu'il faut ajouter quelque chose pour que... ça marche.
Or... *ça marche!*

Bon... elle peut être dite moins ***efficace*** qu'une autre. Gauss par ex.

Oui! Elle est *coûteuse* en **calcul**. Mais en calcul tout court. Je veux dire à qui que ce soit de le faire. À la popogne comme sur la bécane.

Je ne vois donc pas bien la nécessité d'ajouter quoi que ce soit à *calcul*.

Comment: Merci. computationnellement est-il d'usage ?

Comment: @Dimitris : Je ne l'ai jamais ni lu ni entendu. Si tu veux souligner le fait que le *calcul* est fait par un ordinateur alors tu ajoutes : *sur ordinateur*. Je sais bien que la mode est venue de remplacer ce *sur ordinateur* par ***numérique***. Adjectif qui m'a toujours semblé bien curieux quand on le fait épithète de... *calcul*... ! ;-)

Comment: @aCOSwt tant que ce n'est pas "digital"...

Comment: @Destal : :-) Ha oui! C'est aussi très curieux ça les ordis qui comptent sur leurs doigts. Après... après... je suis bien d'accord avec Jean Paulhan : *... Si les mots ne changeaient pas de sens et les sens de mots, que resterait-il donc à dire ?*

Comment: Moi non plus je n'ai jamais lu ou entendu *computationnellement*

Comment: J'ai souvent entendu *computationellement*

Answer (score 1):

1/

> <s>La méthode de Cramer est insuffisante sur le plan des calculs  (computationally inefficient).</s>

Comme user **[aCOSwt](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/40390/17649)** je crois que « insuffisante » ne convient pas très bien; de plus « computationnel » est un terme de l'informatique et non des mathématiques, ce qui fait que « calcul » est ambigu ; une formulation plus appropriée serait la suivante.

- La méthode de Cramer [1] souffre/a de sévère limitations sur le plan des calculs informatiques.

2/

> La méthode de Cramer est <s>insuffisante</s> computationnellement.

- La méthode de Cramer [1] souffre/a de sévère limitations computationnellement.

3/

Dans le présent cas « couteux » n'est pas très spécifique, mais on n'est pas forcé d'être spécifique tout le temps et donc la phrase convient.

> [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/couteux) couteux 2. Au fig. a) Qui nécessite la réalisation d'une chose difficile et/ou désagréable.

> La méthode de Cramer est coûteuse sur le plan des calculs informatiques

On peut cependant être plus spécifique et en même temps supprimer la second locution.

- La méthode de Cramer est coûteuse en temps de calcul informatique.

4/

La dernière phrase convient.

> La méthode de Cramer est coûteuse  computationnellement.

On peut dire « couteuse en temps » si l'on désire être plus spécifique.